# How to set up Tailwind responsive variants for production build?

Tags: create-react-app, tailwind-css, craco

I set up responsive variants in my `create-react-app` app after setting up Craco according to Tailwind Docs. These work perfectly in development build but no images load in production build. What am I missing here?

I have determined the issue is most likely in my production configuration. When I "hard-code" any of the `background-image` URLs directly into my App.css file as a test, they show up correctly in production build.

**index.css**

```js
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  @variants responsive {
    .test-XS {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/.../test-XS.png');
    }
    .test-SM {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/.../test-SM.png');
    }
    .test-MD {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/.../test-MD.png');
    }
    .test-LG {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/.../test-LG.png');
    }
    .test-XL {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/.../test-XL.png');
    }
  }
  /* There are about 20 more sets of these for different images */
}
```

**package.json :**

```js
{
  "homepage": "http://xxx.github.io/yyy",
  "name": "color-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

**craco.config.js :**

```js
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

**tailwind.config.js :**

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was in the concatenation I was using in my `className`s.

It is covered in Tailwind's documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html).

*"Don't use string concatenation to create class names"*

An example of what I was doing incorrectly:

```
<div className={`card bg-contain ${props.image}-XS sm:${props.image}-SM md:${props.image}-MD lg:${props.image}-LG xl:${props.image}-XL`}>
```

My workaround to get my project deployed for now: Changing it so that Tailwind does not "tree-shake" the utilities layer by specifying which layers to purge in config (more info in Tailwind Docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#purging-specific-layers)):

**tailwind.config.js :**

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    layers: ['base', 'components'],
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html']
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I am sure that this makes my build size unnecessarily large, but at least my project is deployed until I figured out a better way to incorporate these dynamic class variants.